# Confusion about Spring Cloud Microservice Architecture

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

When you create a Spring Cloud Microservice Architecture, specifically Eureka in this question, there are mainly 3 parts:

- Eureka Service Discovery.
- Config Server.
- Other Services.

And you want to **have the ability to make multiple instances of each**.

The problem I encounter is: When you make other Service, you need to configure either:

- A **static address** to the Config Server.
- A **static address** to the Eureka Server.

For example, a static address to the Config Server:

```yaml
spring:
    config:
        import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8001
```

I don't want to do this because there could be another instance of Config Server on port 8002, now you have to change the IP for each new instances of other Service.

You can use `Discovery First bootstrap` to avoid this by making other Services find the Config Server so you don't have to define an IP like above, but now you need the Eureka Server IP in `bootstrap.yml` using `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone`.

Or you can centralize the `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` into a Config-repo that the Config Server will fetch from and apply it to new other service instances. This struggle with the same issue of you have to define static IP through `spring.config.import`.

What's the recommended way of configuring Microservice Architecture?

Comment: Something has to be well known first either config server or discovery server.

Comment: Which is the preferred way of configuring?

Comment: They're is no preferred way. You just need to pick one.

Comment: I guess a better question is, what's the pros and cons of each. What's your preferred way and why did you choose to do one over the other.

Comment: I don't have a preference. The default in spring cloud is config first. The default at Netflix is discovery first. Either way, they have to live at well known addresses either way.